# JDBC: select entities with Many to one relation

Tags: jdbc, foreign-keys, entity

I have the two entity classes with bi-directional Many-to-one relation.

```
class A {
  @Column(name="ID")
  long Id;
}

class B {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
  A a;

}
```

The entities are well-coded with additional data fields and getters and setters. And now I want to construct a query string to fetch data from table B, where B's "A_ID" column is equal to A's "ID".
I tried something like this:

```
"select b.data1, b.data2 from B b, A a WHERE b.a.Id=a.Id"
```

But it does not work. What is the correct way to construct such a query? And if A and B are in a uni directional relation, would there be any difference?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join the tables, the whole idea behind @ManyToOne and @OneToMany is to do away with the need for most joins.

I refer you to a tutorial on JPA, like http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany.

Now, without seeing your actual db definitions it's a bit difficult to guess the actual structure of your program and database, but it should be something like this:

```
class A {
  @Id
  @Column(name="ID")
  long Id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="a") 
  List<B> bees;
}

class B {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="A_ID") // Note that A_ID is a column in the B table!!!
  A a;    
}
```

With the example above you could just `select` any list of B's you need, and JPA will automatically fetch the associated A for each found B.  You don't need to do anything to be able to access it, b.a.Id will just work.

As we also have the OneToMany relationship, every A can have multiple B's associated with it.  So, for any `select` that fetches a set of A's, each returned A's `bees` field will give access to the proper list of B objects, without the need to pull the B able into the query.